# Pasar datos a app.blade.php en laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que quiero pasarle datos a mi **app.blade.php** en laravel, eso lo quiero hacer ya que tengo un **side bar** y quiero mostrar todos los elementos de una tabla de mi base de datos en el mismo, ¿como puedo pasar los datos a mi vista de forma "correcta"? o ¿que puedo hacer para suplir esa manera de hacerlo?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré resolver mi problema de la forma en la que lo explica [la documentación de laravel en esta pagina](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views).

Comment: (No respondas al comentario), lo ideal y oportuno es explicar con ejemplos como lo solucionaste, ten en cuenta que si el enlace vence entonces la información se puede perder

Answer (score 0):

[Aquí tienes varias opciones](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views), en lo personal me gusta mas la de usar la función compact de php

```
Dentro del controlador:

// haz la consulta
$datos = Modelo::all();

// enviar como segundo parámetro los datos a enviar
// compact recibe un string y tienes que escribir el nombre de la variable.
return view('app', compact('datos'));
```

Accede a los datos usando la sintaxis de blade con la doble llave:

```
<div><p class="encabezado">{{ $datos[0]['nombre'] }}</p></div>
```